# Смена шаблона в битрикс, пропадает комплексный компонент

Tags: битрикс

Есть компонент news размещен в папке блог, при смене шаблона пропадают все элементы, появляются если включить режим редактирования. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Возможно, ошибка в шаблоне. Где-нибудь не закрыт тег.

Comment: Спасибо))) запарился даже не посмотрел) попадал в скрытый див)